# How to secure wcf serivce with facebook auth?

Tags: facebook, wcf, security, authentication, oauth

I'm building mobile application (with PhoneGap/Cordova).
In order to use my app, the client must authenticate with facebook.

I would like to use that facebook auth mechanism for securing my wcf service. I was thinking of using it like that:

First registration:

1. Client sign-in into facebook and gets an access token
2. Client sends its access token to my wcf service
3. In my service, i extend the access token (to get a long-lived token), and store it in DB with a new record for the new member
4. I send response to the client with the extended token and the member id
5. Client stores the token and member id in its mobile device

When the client enters the application:

1. Client redirects to faceebok
2. If authentication by facebook failed (may be because of various of reasons), he reauthorizes my application.
3. Facebook redirect the client back to my application with new token
4. If token is not changed (compared to the stored token in the device), break.
5. Client sends my wcf service the old token + the new token
6. The wcf compares the old token received with the stored token in db (using the member id)  to identify the client, and raises exception if not equal.
7. In my service, i extend the access token (to get a long-lived token), and store it in DB
8. I send response to the client with the extended token
9. Client overides the old token with the new one in its mobile device

For every request from my mobile application to my wcf service:

1. The client sends the request and the first parameter it passes is its facebook token he stored in the device. the second parameter is the member id.
2. The wcf compares the token received with the stored token in db (using the member id) to identify the client, and raises exception if not equal.
3. process the request

For conclusion, i used the facebook token for identifying the client. in addition, i can use SSL for securing in the network level. Is this a good approach? Thank you for your help.